# Issue with contains() method

Tags: java, contains

I'm writing a simple code using `contains()` method, but the problem is that if I put a string array in the argument of `contains()` method, the program does nothing (no error). So, it just has to loop over one string array and look whether it contains an element from the second array. I tried with one single word in the argument and it works fine. The arrays are not null and I can print them. So, any suggestion?

This is the part of the code:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < farbe.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < names.length; j++) {
                if(names[j].contains(farbe[i])) {
                    System.out.println(names[j]+"\t"+"yes");
                }
            }
        }
```

The arrays elements are read from the .*txt file. So, the 'names' array has word sequences and the 'color' array contains the color. The parts from the arrays:

Names:

> Herrenlederjacke >>Collins
>   Herrenstoffjacke >>M H7 4B
>   9-LV (schwarz | 54)
>   9-LV (schwarz | 52)
>   Tunika-Lederkleid >>9519

Color:

> beige
>   braun
>   schwarz

The arrays are big, so I put  just a little part.

Comment: Why do you start with `i = 1` and `j = 1`? Array Index start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: No, 'names' array contains an element from an array 'farbe'.

Comment: Could you add some example of arrays with elements and result you would want to get? It is not clear what are you trying to do. Are you trying to check if (or find) element(s) from one array is fragment of some element of second array (something like `"abc".contains("bc")`)?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, I need to know whether the element contains the word or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be that java arrays start at index 0. Also, your braces are misplaced in the contains line. Try :

```
for(int i = 0; i < farbe.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < names.length; j++){
            if(Arrays.asList(names[j].contains(farbe[i]))){
                System.out.println(names[j]+"\t"+"yes");
            }
                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line from your file is separate element in array we will have

```
String[] names={
        "Names:",
        "Herrenlederjacke >>Collins",
        "Herrenstoffjacke >>M H7 4B",
        "9-LV (schwarz | 54)",
        "9-LV (schwarz | 52)",
        "Tunika-Lederkleid >>9519"
};
String[] farbe={
        "beige",
        "braun",
        "schwarz",
};
```

to check which color exists in `names` you can use this code

```
for (String color : farbe) {//will iterate over all colors
    namesLoop:
    for(String name :names){//will iterate over all names
        if (name.contains(color)){
            System.out.println(color+"\t yes");
            break namesLoop;//we found this color, we can skip to next one
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that, if I specify the elements of array 'farbe' it works with this code as well, but when I initialize it and then read the text file and copy the lines to the array, it doesn't work. This is really strange, because on another computer it works normally.

Comment: Try to print content of `farbe` array while after you initialized it from file. Also by "it doesn't work" you mean that it throws some exception or just ends without errors but also without correct output?

Comment: I tried also to print both arrays separately and it's ok. I can see the content. By telling "it doesn't work", I mean there is no error, but also no output.

Comment: @ArmMiner Are you sure that array is filled correctly? Maybe instead of {"a","b","c"} you have only one element {"abc"}? If algorithm using the same array works on one machine then it must work on the other, unless content of array is different.

Comment: I copied the same files from the machine where it's working and also I tried with only one color in the text file and it works.

Comment: Not really, because I don't need just a one color.

Comment: Without code that you use on both computers I can't solve this problem. Maybe ask another question on SO and include this code. I am sure many people will try to help you, not just me :)